# image orientation changes when saved in local after capture from front camera

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, front-camera, uiimageorientation

Hello all i am facing a problem regarding orientation of image, when saved on local storage. But the strange thing is that when i capture from the **REAR** camera and get it from storage path it works fine but when i capture it from **FRONT** camera and get it from storage path the orientation changes and that to the orientation changes differently for different devices.Please guys help me to get over this, here is my code

```
 Bitmap myBitmap = decodeFile(imgFile,imageWidth,imageHeight);
 Bitmap orientedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), myBitmap);
 mainImage.setImageBitmap(orientedBitmap);
```

The **ExifUtil.Java** file code is here in [this link](https://gist.github.com/9re/1990019)

Comment: `ExifUtil.rotateBitmap)'`. You are blindly rotating every bitmap. Why? And nobody can see how much and in which direction.

Comment: `Thank You in advance`. Please do not thank in advance. Makes a bad impression.

Comment: `mainImage.setImageBitmap(orientedBitmap);`. Change to `mainImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);`. Orientation adaption should be done by decodeFile().